# using Nito AsyncEx/AsyncInLine to lead with async filePicker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

I'm new at async world and i started developing some stuff for windows store apps.
My problem is that i need to wait the async method of filepicker ends to do other stuff.

So i tried search for: "run synchronous and asynchronous method c#" and i ended on Stephen Cleary blog. I tryed to use Nito AsyncEx to lead with my problem and it doesn't work because when i call the following method it doesn't stop.

```
private List<Templates> classModel = new List<Templates>();
private void btnLoadClassExercises_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   AsyncContext.Run(() => loadFile());
   // do some stuff with classModel
}

private async void loadFile()
{
   FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
   openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");
   var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
   classModel = xml.getControlClass(file);
 }
```

During my search i found a classe called AsyncInLine that helped me out with some others stuffs like this one. But with this specific situation, i didn't work too. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/163ef755-ff7b-4ea5-b226-bbe8ef5f4796)

Can someone help me?

Edit #1:

```
    //When i click on this button, it loads the file and all canvas are drawn on canvasSegment.
    private async void btnLoadClassExercises_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (classModel != null)
            {
                FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");
                var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                classModel = xml.getControlClass(file);

                auxCV = 0;
                if (editClass)
                    CanvasSegment.Children.Clear();
                foreach (Templates temp in classModel)
                    createCanvasSegment(temp);
                editClass = true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    // When i want to del some canvas, i put the removeCV = true and click on a canvas
    private void btnDelExercise_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        classEdit = classModel; //To debuf if the classModel.Count = 0
        removeCV = true;
    }

    //When i click on a canvas, if removeCV = false, i draw the canvas on the main canvas(canvasClass), otherwise, i delete it. The problem is here. My modelClass.count here is = 0.  
    private void cv_PointerPressed(Templates temp, Canvas cv)
    {
        if (!removeCV)
        {
            foreach (StackPanel sp in CanvasSegment.Children)
                foreach (Canvas c in sp.Children)
                    c.Opacity = 1;

            cv.Opacity = 0.8;
            canvasClass.Children.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Shapes.Count; i++)
            {
                //Do some stuff with points and draws on CanvasClass later
                rh.renderModel(new InkManager(), canvasClass, temp.Shapes[i], true, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= classModel.Count; i++)
                if (classModel[i] == temp)
                {
                    classModel.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }

            CanvasSegment.Children.Clear();
            auxCV = 0;
            foreach (Templates tempModel in classModel)
                createCanvasSegment(tempModel);
            removeCV = false;
        }
    }

    //I create a mini canvas foreach template in file.
    private void createCanvasSegment(Templates temp)
    {
        Thickness thk = new Thickness();
        thk.Right = 5;
        thk.Bottom = 5;
        if (temp != null || temp.Shapes != null)
        {
            if (auxCV == 0)
            {
                spcv = new StackPanel();
                spcv.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                spcv.Width = 540;
            }
            Canvas cv = new Canvas()
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat),
                Name = temp.Template,
                Height = 73.125,
                Width = 130,
                Margin = thk,
            };

            cv.PointerPressed += (s, e) => cv_PointerPressed(temp, cv);
            foreach (ShapePoints tempshapePoints in temp.Shapes)
            {
                ShapePoints tempS = tempShapePoints;
                if (!removeCV)
                {
                    //Do some stuff with points
                }
                rh.renderModel(new InkManager(), cv, tempS, true, false);
            }

            auxCV++;
                spcv.Children.Add(cv);
            if (auxCV == 1)
                CanvasSegment.Children.Add(spcv);
            else if (auxCV == 4)
                auxCV = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is already in a UI thread's context, there's no need for `AsyncContext.Run` - just use:

```
private async void btnLoadClassExercises_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await loadFile());
   // do some stuff with classModel
}

// Make this task returning (or even return the list instead of setting a local)
private async Task loadFile()
{
   FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
   openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");
   var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
   classModel = xml.getControlClass(file);
 }
```

Comment: Initially i made like that, but it won't work for what i want.
The stuff i'm going to do with classModel is create a canvas for "each Model" the file have. And for each canvas, i had a clickevent which deletes the clicked canvas and creates the canvas again.
But when i use the clickevent i get classModel.Count = 0;

Comment: @Kelianosevis You need to make sure the canvases, and their click events, are created after the file is loaded.  Putting the construction after the file is loaded should take care of that for you.

Comment: My canvases and their click events are created after the file is loaded. I'm sure of it, because they are drawn on the stackpanel. I have a button to activate the "delete mode" and when i click on a canvas the click event deletes me the clicked canvas. Now, on the delete button, i created another list of templates on this button made anotherList = classModel and when i debugged it the classModel.count is = 0. But, how i said before, all canvas are drawn.

Comment: @Kelianosevis You'd need to show a small, reproducable code set to be able to help.

Comment: Done. Can you see the problem?

Comment: @Kelianosevis I don't - and the code isn't self-runnable, so I can't try to debug it...